# Как передать функцию в класс снаружи класса?

Tags: android, kotlin

Есть класс в котором выполняется проверка условия, но важным параметром для неё является одно значение которое я бы хотел передавать в этот класс снаружи в зависимости от ситуации. Например: есть EditText состояние зависит от того что в него введено, есть таких полей несколько и они будут вести себя по разному, например один будет принимать одну форму при введённых трёх символах, а второй при 6ти, третий же туже форму только при условии что это будут буквы и т.д.
Вроде бы то как Kotlin позволяет, но как это произвести не могу понять. Вижу примерно это так:

```
//EditTex
var validation = false
if (validation) {
    //первая форма
} else {
    //вторая форма
}

//MainActivity
fun onCreate() {
     editText.validation = editText.text.length > 2
}
```

Нужно что бы объект EditText постоянно проверял условие `editText.text.length > 2`, а не использовал уже вычисленный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно воспользоваться событием onTextChanged

```
EditText searchTo = findViewById(R.id.medittext);
searchTo.addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public fun afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public fun onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // Здесь смотрим длину текста и т.д.
    } 
});
```

Приблизительно как-то так. Оригинальный пример на Java [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432083/how-to-use-edittext-ontextchanged-event-when-i-press-the-number).

Comment: Спасибо, но это немного не то.